# Removing portions of .tgz filename and moving into newly created directories, then extract. Bash Shell

Tags: bash, shell

I have done some searching around but couldn't find something that really helped what I needed.

I am trying to rename all .tgz files in dir, create dirs using new filenames,and mv all .tgz files to new directories using shell/bash.

---

Example:

INITIAL STATE:

```
data/results/
    test_a.1.0.11.class.tgz
    test_b.1.0.12.class.tgz
    test_c.1.0.13.class.tgz
    test_d.1.0.14.class.tgz
    test_d.1.0.15.class.tgz
```

RESULT STATE:

```
data/compared/1.0.11to1.0.12/
      1.0.11.class.tgz
      1.0.12.class.tgz

data/compared/1.0.12to1.0.13/
      1.0.12.class.tgz
      1.0.13.class.tgz

data/compared/1.0.13to1.0.14/
      1.0.13.class.tgz
      1.0.14.class.tgz

data/compared/1.0.14to1.0.15/
      1.0.14.class.tgz
      1.0.15.class.tgz
```

Also, having part of the script that will extract all .tgz tarfiles in same final directory would be great.

Example:

data/compared/1.0.14to1.0.15/
      1.0.14.class.tgz
      1.0.15.class.tgz
      /extractedTar1.0.14
      /extractedTar1.0.15

Thanks a ton, all!

---

What I've tried so far:

## !/bin/bash

```
for full_filename in *.tgz; do
    extension="$full_{filename##*.}"
    filename="$full_filename%.*}"
    mkdir -p "$filename"
    mv "$full_filename" "$filename/"
done
```

As you can see this doesn't do exactly what I want at all.

---

---

EDIT: Extra functionality request!
The tarballs each consist of a single(/test) directory which houses many other dir/files. 
E.g. 1.0.11.class.tgz consists of a respective"/test" directory.

Is there a way to extract each of these tarballs, being careful to rename the extracted /"test" directory to something like "test_1.0.11" before accidentally extracting the other tarball into the same "/test" directory? Thanks a ton!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'll add an edit to my above post of what I tried so far.

Comment: What I've tried added.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the tarballs have flat file structures (no directories) and that you're in the "data" directory.

You said "mv all .tgz files to new directories" yet you have in your "RESULT STATE" example two of some of those files.  I assume you meant "cp" (copy).  If you want to copy and then move, change the second `cp` line to `mv` as noted in the comments.

```
#!/bin/sh
last=
for tgz in results/*.tgz; do           # loop on all .tgz files in results/
  if [ -n "$last" ]; then
    target="compared/${last#*.}"       # e.g. compared/1.0.11.class.tgz
    target="${target%.*.*}to${tgz#*.}" # e.g. compared/1.0.11to1.0.12.class.tgz
    target="${target%.*.*}"            # e.g. compared/1.0.11to1.0.12
    mkdir -p "$target"
    cp -p "$last" "$target/${last#*.}" # skips "test_a." prefix
    cp -p "$tgz"  "$target/${tgz#*.}"  # change this to mv to move
  fi
  last="$tgz"
done
```

original:

```
$ ls -1R results
results:
test_a.1.0.11.class.tgz
test_b.1.0.12.class.tgz
test_c.1.0.13.class.tgz
test_d.1.0.14.class.tgz
test_d.1.0.15.class.tgz
```

output:

```
$ ls -1R compared/*
compared/1.0.11to1.0.12:
1.0.11.class.tgz
1.0.12.class.tgz

compared/1.0.12to1.0.13:
1.0.12.class.tgz
1.0.13.class.tgz

compared/1.0.13to1.0.14:
1.0.13.class.tgz
1.0.14.class.tgz

compared/1.0.14to1.0.15:
1.0.14.class.tgz
1.0.15.class.tgz
```

---

For the "Extra functionality request," add the following after the second `cp` command:

```
  tar -C "$target" -pzxf "$last"
  mv "$target/test" "$target/test_${last%.class.tgz}"
  tar -C "$target" -pzxf "$tgz"
  mv "$target/test" "$target/test_${tgz%.class.tgz}"
```

(Note, this requires GNU tar for `-C DIR`, which is listed in `tar --help` but *not* `man tar`.)

If you don't need the tarballs, remove the `cp` commands.

Comment: Awesome, absolutely excellent. My appreciated. Yes, you are correct, the newly created dirs do have repeat files so a cp makes much more sense than mv.

Comment: The tarballs each consist of a single directory which houses many other dir/files. E.g. 1.0.11.class.tgz all consist of a /test/ directory. Is there a way to extract each of these tarballs, being careful to rename the extracted /"test" directory to something like "test_1.0.11" to ensure both tarballs in each compared/1.0.11to1.0.12 does get extracted into one /test? Thanks a ton!